# Access azure internal LB via s2s vpn

Tags: azure-aks, azure-vpn, internal-load-balancer

I created s2s VPN between AWS and Azure.
The peering works fine and pods can connect to each other.
The issue only with LB service on AKS side - I can't connect from AWS there.
config on azure side:

- vnet cidr - 10.240.0.0/16
- default subnet cidr - 10.240.64.0/18
- azure pod ip - 10.240.65.43 (success)
- azure LB ip - 10.240.66.37 (issue)

Security group on Azure:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "default" {
  name                = "nsg-${var.environment}"
  location            = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}
```

I tried curl *AKS pod ip* from *EKS pod* - **ok**

I tried curl azure LB ip:

- from AKS pod - **ok**
- from peered EKS pod - **not ok**

LB sku is **standard**

**UPDATE:**
LB recreation fixed the issue.
But for next time cluster creation - faced the same problem. no changes in terraform, just reapplying.